# Tkinter's mainloop() Calling Button Function Automatically

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm pretty new to Tkinter but starting to try to put more complex GUI's in my scripts. So this must be pretty basic but I can't figure out what's going wrong.

What I want is pretty simple, a bunch of data entry options and at the bottom an exit and submit buttons. It seems though that mainloop() or something else keeps running the button's command without any user input. Thus because of the exit button, the applet is destroyed before it even shows up. If I put the buttons outside of the mainloop(), there is no problem, but of course it doesn't make sense and the buttons don't show up.

```
button_exit = Tkinter.Button(root, text = 'Exit', command = root.destroy())
button_exit.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=10, sticky='E')
button_query = Tkinter.Button(root, text = 'Query', command = intQuery())
button_query.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, sticky='E')

root.mainloop()
```

That's basically the problem area of the code. The rest is just that data entry fields, most of the script hasn't even been written yet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
command = root.destroy()
```

to

```
command = root.destroy
```

The reason is this: The parentheses call the method, and method arguments are evaluated *before* being passed to the method. This is why your program is exiting too early.

Without the parentheses, you are referencing the method as an *object* which can be passed to the Tkinter.Button, stored, and called later when the button is pressed.

Then do the same with `command = intQuery()`.

Comment: Thanks! That does make sense but never would've thought of that. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Also try `command=lambda: root.destroy()` as example

**UPD:** just notices, that question was asked 11 years ago...

Comment: This is just adds an unnecessary anonymous function. The existing answer is simpler, clearer, and more efficient.